# How do I set the onClick in the navbar of material-ui?

Tags: reactjs

Below is the code for creating the navigation bar/header for an application. I have used material-ui.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingCartOutlined";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  flex: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
});

class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <AppBar position="static" elevation={0}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            className={classes.menuButton}
            color="contrast"
            onClick={this.props.toggleDrawer}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography className={classes.flex} type="title" color="inherit">
            Pizza Shop
          </Typography>
          <div>
            <IconButton color="contrast" onClick={this.props.cart}>
              <ShoppingCartOutlinedIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton color="contrast" onClick={this.props.login}>
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}

Nav.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Nav);
```

I'm new to 'props' and I'm not sure what `this.props.cart` or `this.props.login` will do. I want to create a functionality where when I click on the above two icons, I'm directed to some another component, but I'm not sure how to do it. Please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

`Props` are just parameters that the parent component sent to the children component. In your example `this.props.cart` and `this.props.login` are functions ( I am not sure about the `cart`, but it is used as a function ). From your example, when you click on the icons, you will call `cart` and `login` functions sent from the parent.

The answer to your question "How do you set onClick" is you already doing it on the `login` function/method. So you need to look at the parent component implementation.

Below I wrote a much more readable example, so feel free to look

```
import React from 'react'

class ChildrenComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // This is doing the same thing, just we call the function / method in little different way
    // return <div onClick={() => { this.props.onShoppingSubmit() }}>Aaa</div>
    return <div onClick={this.props.onShoppingSubmit}>Aaa</div>
  }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  handleShoppingSubmit = () => {
    // Do what every that function needs to do
    console.log('Hi from parent')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildrenComponent onShoppingSubmit={this.handleShoppingSubmit} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Krystian. Can I define cart() and login() inside my class Nav? Because IconButton is a class pre-defined in material-ui.. I cannot myself define any function inside IconButton

Comment: Of course, you can. It is only up to you where you will use it.